After rigging my mesh to armature, moving the body moves other vertices?
So when I rig my mesh to the armature, I do it by 100% weights only and not vertices have multiple parent bones. However when I move my mesh (Without the armature) then the legs and feet seem to move an exaggerated amount and in different directions...
Here is what I'm talking about:


I've tried double checking the weights as well as using alt+P to clear parents and re-rig all the vertices but it still ends up having the same results.
I know this may seem like no big deal because why would I want to move the mesh independent from the bones anyway, but for the game I'm importing this into it matter because it causes glitches. Anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

hello, remove these vertices from all vertex groups and assign them to the correct group?

I do believe this will always happen and is "normal behavior". Something like, for each bone down the hierarchy, the offset will cumulate from its parent. Top-level bone is offset from the mesh object origin, second-level bone doubles the offset, etc. What kind of glitch are you having in your game engine? How can you tell whether it is caused by "that" or anything else?

Alright, good to know that it's normal. I just assumed it was the problem in my game engine because the same pieces moving were the pieces that stretched in the game. But it turns out I have to handle weighted vertices different through the code and it was the programming the whole time. Thanks for the explanation

This is right, you shouldn't move mesh. If you want to move the whole character, move armature root bone.

